# Searching through dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Not sure how to show a results chart of what I want, but see below what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to create the rcnew column to take where an rc is in '098000' or '999998' and change that to the rc from the closest previous paydate where the rc is not in '098000' or '999998'. As you can see, my code has where paydate is equal, that's because I can't figure out how to go about this. If there is no equal paydate, I want to take the rpevious one. The NULL in the results below should be 200000.

```
ern rc      paydate     rcnew
123 098000  20151221    NULL
123 200000  20151214    200000
456 098000  20151221    200000
456 200000  20151221    200000



   SELECT
    ern, rc, paydate, 
    CASE WHEN fss1.rc in ('098000', '999998') 
         THEN (SELECT TOP 1 rc
               FROM [FIN_DataMart].[dbo].[FSSpaydetl] fss
               WHERE fss.ern = fss1.ern
               AND rc not in ('098000', '999998')
               AND fss.paydate = fss1.paydate
               ORDER BY paydate DESC)
         ELSE fss1.rc
    END rcnew
FROM [FIN_DataMart].[dbo].[FSSpaydetl] fss1

GROUP BY ern, rc, paydate
ORDER BY ern, paydate desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lag()` will not work if you have multiple special values in a row.  An alternative is `outer apply`:

```
select fss.ern, rss.rc, fss.paydate,
       (case when fss.rc in ('098000', '999998') then fss2.rc else fss.rc end)
from FIN_DataMart].[dbo].[FSSpaydetl] fss outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from FIN_DataMart].[dbo].[FSSpaydetl] fss fss2
      where fss2.paydate < fss2.paydate and
            fss2.ern = fss.ern and
            fss2.rc not in ('098000', '999998')
      order by fss2.paydate desc
     ) fss2;
```

Comment: Good catch in his code i believe you are correct that his question probably meant to write "closest previous paydate where rc is not '098000' or '999998'" but he didn't

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to put. But I will try outer apply and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LAG` Function, if you meant "`rc` from the closest previous `paydate`" but as @GordonLinoff appropriately devised it looks like you are actually looking for the "`rc` from the closest previous `paydate` that is not `'098000', '999998'` in which case this solution will not work.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (enc INT, rc CHAR(6), paydate DATE)
INSERT INTO @Table (enc, rc, paydate)
VALUES (123,'098000','20151221')
,(123,'200000','20151214')
,(456,'098000','20151221')
,(456,'200000','20151221')

SELECT
    *
    ,LagResult = LAG(rc,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY paydate)
    ,rcnew = CASE
       WHEN rc IN ('098000','999998') THEN LAG(rc,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY paydate)
       ELSE rc
    END
FROM
    @Table
ORDER BY
    paydate
```